Springboot error creating bean DataSourceConfiguration after creating dynamic oracle datasources
I am upgrading to Springboot 3.2.4 from 1.5.1. The source code is compiling but I'm having a small issue at runtime.  While using 1.5.1 I was able to create multiple Oracle datasource beans and use springboot actuator to get the db health of the connections.
However, with 3.2.4 I'm getting the following error when DataSourceAutoConfiguration is enabled even though I've registered two oracle datasources which I can see in the logs before the following error:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

I'm also getting the following warning before the error above:
WARN o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext:632 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pathMappedEndpoints' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/WebEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.PathMappedEndpoints]: Factory method 'pathMappedEndpoints' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthContributorRegistry' parameter 2: Error creating bean with name 'dbHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dbHealthContributor' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

I don't have the standard spring.datasource.* config because I'm using the following beanPostProcessor to create the datasources with custom config.
@Bean
    static BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor beanPostProcessor(final ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
        return new BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor() {
            public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory arg0) throws BeansException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
            }

            public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry beanRegistry) throws BeansException {
                createDynamicBeans(environment,beanRegistry);
                
            }
            
        };
    }

'createDynamicBeans' is using beanRegistry.registerBeanDefinition and the configuration below to create the beans dynamically based on the config files.
spring.datasource.datasource_1.url=jdbc:<HOST>
spring.datasource.datasource_1.username=<USER>
spring.datasource.datasource_1.password=<PW>
spring.datasource.datasource_1.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.datasource_1.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.datasource_1.validation-query=SELECT 1 from dual
spring.datasource.datasource_1.validation-interval=0

spring.datasource.datasource_2.url=jdbc:<HOST>
spring.datasource.datasource_2.username=<USER>
spring.datasource.datasource_2.password=<PW>
spring.datasource.datasource_2.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.datasource_2.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.datasource_2.validation-query=SELECT 1 from dual
spring.datasource.datasource_2.validation-interval=0

'datasource_1' is set to the Primary
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.10.5'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.4.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.4.0'
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'

    implementation 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc10:19.22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.oracle.database.security:oraclepki:23.3.0.23.09'
    implementation 'com.oracle.database.security:osdt_core:21.13.0.0'
    implementation 'com.oracle.database.security:osdt_cert:21.13.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

I know these datasources are created successfully since if I add the following line I don't get any errors and can connect to the Db's just fine.
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

However, the 'DataSourceHealthIndicator' instance is not created (I assume because of the line above) so I can't see the status of the DB's in the actuator call to health.
Is this a Springboot translation issue from 1.x to 3.x?  Or is there another way to create the dynamic datasource beans so the DataSourceConfiguration recognizes them and does not search for the default spring.datasource.* config which was not used previously in our 1.X version?
Thanks for the help!
Adding spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration fixes the runtime issue and the code is able to connect to the Oracle DB's, but the DataSourceHealthIndicator bean is not created.
UPDATE
After further debugging it looks like DataSourceConfiguration is trying to create a HikariDataSource.  My understanding is that the BasicDataSource's I've already created should prevent this from happening.  Why isn't Springboot recognizing the BasicDataSource's I've created using beanRegistry.registerBeanDefinition?

Adding the following dependencies seems to have fixed the issue:
providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
implementation 'com.h2database:h2:2.2.220'

I'm assuming the tomcat runtime is replacing the default Hikari CP and the h2 lib is creating a default datasource that does not need a connection string.
The info method is now returning the following:
{
    "status": "UP",
    "components": {
        "db": {
            "status": "UP",
            "components": {
                "dataSource": {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "details": {
                        "database": "H2",
                        "validationQuery": "isValid()"
                    }
                },
                "datasource_1": {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "details": {
                        "database": "Oracle",
                        "validationQuery": "isValid()"
                    }
                },
                "datasource_2": {
                    "status": "UP",
                    "details": {
                        "database": "Oracle",
                        "validationQuery": "isValid()"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Not quite perfect, since I now have the embedded h2 datasource that does nothing, but at least the other datasources are working and I can get their status via the /info method again.
